# issue with CallKit: some buttons blink when tapping on mute button

Tags: ios, callkit

I have an issue with CallKit where some of the buttons blink when tapping on mute button.

This happens only when I set `iconTemplateImageData` to `CXProviderConfiguration`.

I made a minimal project for reproducing the issue.

https://github.com/kenjitayama/CallKitIconBlink

There is an animated gif on the top page.

Does anyone have this issue, or know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified that the image you are setting in iconTemplateImageData is a square with side length of 40 points? Also try what happens if you use some other image that has those dimensions. I assume that the problem does not occur if you do not set iconTemplateImageData?

Comment: Yes, the images are from a CallKit example project called Speakerbox, and they are 40 points square size.
https://github.com/Lax/Learn-iOS-Swift-by-Examples/tree/master/Speakerbox/Speakerbox/Assets.xcassets/IconMask.imageset
My own images had the same issue.
Yes, the problem does not occur if I comment out where I set iconTemplateImageData.

Comment: Maybe it actually is a bug. Have you filed it with Apple yet?